# php image not being fetched stdClass

Tags: php, html, image

```
<?php

require_once'header.php';
require_once'eloMath.php';

    $votedIds = [3];
    $votedIdsString = implode(',', $votedIds);

    //$query = "SELECT 'GameID' FROM `voteduser` WHERE `UserID`= $_SESSION['username']";

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `game` WHERE ID NOT IN ($votedIdsString) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($db_server, $query2);
    //$result2 = $db_server->query($query2);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)) {
    $images[] = (object) $row;
}

$cover = $row['Cover_Art'] .'"src="GameArt\'. $row';

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game voting</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <center>
<!--
   <?php 
  while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo '<a href="gameRate.php?win=' . $row['ID'] . ' Or loss=' . $row['ID'] . '"><img id="votingGameArt' . $row['Cover_Art'] .'" src="GameArt/'. $cover .'"></a>';
  }
    ?>
-->

       <table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="image"><a href="gameRate.php?win=<?=$images[0]->ID?>&loss=<?=$images[1]->ID?>"><img src="GameArt/<?=$images[0]->$cover?>" /></a></td>
        <td valign="top" class="image"><a href="gameRate.php?win=<?=$images[1]->ID?>&loss=<?=$images[0]->ID?>"><img src="GameArt/<?=$images[1]->$cover?>" /></a></td>
    </tr>
        </center>
</body>


    </html>
```

I am trying to fetch two cover arts and display them within the table, but instead of showing the art work, it isn't displaying anything and instead of showing me an error, is instead displaying a notice saying undefined property stdClass::$

how would i go about fixing this

Comment: You are escaping the single quote in your $cover variable

Comment: can you point out where as i am struggling to see

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand, what you want to do with this:

```
$cover = $row['Cover_Art'] .'"src="GameArt\'. $row';
```

You try to use `$row` as an array, but it contains object, because it's fetched with `mysqli_fetch_object()`.

In addition, you use `$row` outside of fetching cycle, so it contains only last fetched value.

And finally, are you sure you want to use `$cover` as an object property name? Because this construction `$images[0]->$cover` is used, when you need to access a property by name, that is not known before execution. If you need to access a property, named "cover", you should write `$images[0]->cover` instead.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure to be honest, I'm in the process of learning PHP. But it was oddly enough a question someone asked on here that led me to that $cover line of code. I'm trying to define a variable that pulls the image from the database to display it as i can't seem to work out why the image isn't actually displaying.  

echo '<a href="gameRate.php?win=' . $row['ID'] . ' Or loss=' . $row['ID'] . '"><img id="votingGameArt' . $row['Cover_Art'] .'" src="GameArt/'. $cover .'"></a>';

it was showing ion that line of code, but then the math behind the website wasnt working, so i switched